# Accessing Json Array from appsettings using Options .NET C#

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, appsettings

I've already searched, there are similar questions, but with JSON Array in answers they are using `IConfigure` in the controller. I can use `IConfigure` only in Startup.

I have this JSON Array in `appsettings.json`

```
{
  "EmailList":[
    {
      "name":"John Algovich",
      "email":"John.Algovich@mail.com"
    },
    {
      "name":"Petr Algr",
      "email":"Petr.Algr@mail.com"
    },
    {
      "name":"Mathew Cena",
      "email":"Mathew.Cena@mail.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

`EmailList.cs`:

```
public class EmailAddress {
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class EmailList {
  public List<EmailAddress> EmailArray { get; set; }
}
```

There is a lot of injections in `Startup.cs`, so I used the same code for mine:

```
services.Configure<EmailList>(Configuration.GetSection("EmailList"));
```

`Controller`:

```
public class DevController : Controller
    {
        private readonly EmailList _devEmailList;
        private List<string> _emailList;

        public DevController(

            IOptions<EmailList> _devEmailList,
        {

            _devEmailList = devEmailList.Value; 
            
            _emailList = new List<string>();

        }
    }
```

```
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var result = _devEmailList; // Returns null

            var mailData2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmailList>(_devEmailList.EmailArray.ToString()); // Returns null
        }
```

Goal: How can get email adresses in Controller using Options and add it to the list?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I was able to solve the problem:

I kept my `appsettings.json` the way it is with config classes.

I changed `Startup` code to this:

```
EmailInfo[] emails = Configuration.GetSection("EmailList").Get<EmailInfo[]>();

services.Configure<EmailList>(options => {options.EmailArray = emails.ToList();});
```

In my `Controller`:

This stays the same

```
public class DevController : Controller
    {
        private readonly EmailList _devEmailList;
        private List<string> _emailList;

        public DevController(

            IOptions<EmailList> _devEmailList,
        {

            _devEmailList = devEmailList.Value; 
            
            _emailList = new List<string>();

        }
    }
```

Getting emails:

```
public IActionResult Index() {

    var result = _udeEmailList.EmailArray;

    foreach (var mailInfo in result)
      {
        emailsList.Add(mailInfo.Email);
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

what you are retrieving as your section is `IEnumerable<EmailAddress>` not `EmailList`. Read what you wrote, in your config there's no "EmailArray" definition.

You can add another level in your config (useful if you will have more things relative to email configuration in that section) or change the type to `IEnumerable<EmailAddress>` (not needed to be concretely IEnumerable, anything that implements it like an array or a list will work).

If you go for the first option you must do something like this:

In your config file...

```
{
    "EmailConfig":{
        "EmailList":[
           {
            "name":"John Algovich",
            "email":"John.Algovich@mail.com"
           },
         {
            "name":"Petr Algr",
            "email":"Petr.Algr@mail.com"
         },
         {
            "name":"Mathew Cena",
            "email":"Mathew.Cena@mail.com"
         }
      ]

       //You can add here more properties

   }
}
```

Your config classes:

```
public class EmailAddress
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class EmailConfig
{
    public List<EmailAddress> EmailList { get; set; }
}
```

Your configuration:

```
services.Configure<EmailConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("EmailConfig"));
```

And the controller:

```
public class DevController : Controller
{
    private readonly EmailConfig _mailConfig;

    public DevController(IOptions<EmailConfig> mailConfig)
    {

        _mailConfig = mailConfig.Value;

    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var result = _mailConfig.EmailList;
    }
}
```